# How to set up and use unsolicited remote access (MSRA)?

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-assistance

[This Youtube video shows how to start remote assistance without sending an invitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-buNZTUjnqw)

The video shows someone accessing another computer without sending an invitation (or waiting for the invite to be accepted).

I have tried carrying out all the same steps as him (or as close as I can) in his video, below are the three Inbound firewall rules and the security rule below that:

[image: 3 Inbound rules]

[image: Security rules]

After trying to connect this is what I see:

[image: MSRA not working]

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work? I use remote assistance so often that having to send an invite each time is really annoying.

When there was a choice between domain, private or public networks I chose domain:

[image: Domain chosen]

But I'm not even sure what a domain computer is. I'm using Windows 10 pro, does this only work on say Windows server 2016?

I have the "Server Manager" program he was using in the video:

[image: Server Manager]

but this still doesn't grant unsolicited remote access.

Comment: Wait, why not just... save those passwords in the client?

Comment: @user1686 I tried that, it doesn't work, I have to enter two passwords, one into the Remote Desktop client and another into the remote computer login screen, I save the credentials but it still asks me for them each time.

Comment: That rather sounds like it's caused by GPO settings on the server itself, or possibly on the client. (In fact "remote computer login screen" shouldn't even be _a thing_ anymore, unless someone went and disabled NLA on the server...) Are they domain-joined or standalone?

Comment: @user1686 This is the problem; I don't know what a 'domain' is or how to get one. So I don't understand domain-jointed, sorry.

Comment: We are asking if the server is joined to an Active Directory domain.  How do you have Server Manager on anything except Windows Server?

Comment: @Ramhound I just downloaded that server manager program from Microsoft to try and make the remote access work. What is Windows Server and Active Directory domain?

Comment: @BLAZE - What research have you done on that subject?

Comment: @Ramhound I looked at Wikipedia and a few other sites, but these are just words that make no sense to me, I'm not a computer technician, so my knowledge is very limited. What would be helpful is if someone could just tell me in simple English what needs to be done to achieve unsolicited remote assistance like in that video, for example, 'you need to get a domain first', or 'you need change operating system to Windows Server 2016'.

Comment: If you don't even know what an Active Directory domain requires, saying that's required (it probably isn't), won't be very useful. You are expected to have done some research.  You mention Windows Server 2016, but if you don't even know what is required to run it, mentioning it without that knowledge indicates you have not done your basic research.  Understanding what an active directory domain is is basic knowledge and can be gained by doing 30 minutes of research on the subject.

Comment: @Ramhound Does it seem that it is necessary to know how something works in order to use it? When you use your computer/smartphone you don't need to know the fundamentals of data exchange in information theory or understand how the logic gates work in electronics. All I'm asking you is what is required to get this to work. My 'basic research' is asking this question on this site. As I said before I have read about these words you mention but it is not getting me any closer to solving the problem. How do I set up active directory? Which 'ingredients' I need to solve this problem?